# Converting 1st letter of atom in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How to convert 1st letter of an atom in uppercase letter in LPA prolog? the only way I know is using 'lwrupr'. But it capitalizes all the letters.

Comment: do you want the atom to become a variable or simple something like `x` -> `'X'` ?

Comment: No, I need to print the meaning of some words and requirement is that if any  input is capital letter, then the meaning must be in capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have LPA Prolog available, but here is an educated guess, resulting from a quick read of reference manual: take the first letter from the atom, make it upper case, and rebuild the word

```
first_char_uppercase(WordLC, WordUC) :-
    atom_chars(WordLC, [FirstChLow|LWordLC]),
    atom_chars(FirstLow, [FirstChLow]),
    lwrupr(FirstLow, FirstUpp),
    atom_chars(FirstUpp, [FirstChUpp]),
    atom_chars(WordUC, [FirstChUpp|LWordLC]).
```

In SWI-Prolog, we can test it defining the missing builtin lwrupr/2 like this

```
lwrupr(Low, Upp) :- upcase_atom(Low, Upp).
```

and we get

```
?- first_char_uppercase(carlo,X).
X = 'Carlo'.

?- first_char_uppercase('Carlo',X).
X = 'Carlo'.
```

Comment: It's Ok for Win Prolog. But Not LPA prolog because it's so old and I'm not allowed to use Win prolog

Comment: try using name/2 instead

Comment: Thank You so much, Very difficult to use but name/2 worked well.